# Can access to protected page such as admin.html in address bar

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an issue. I can access to my admin.html and client .html in address bar while I put a login and everything works fine when clicking on the links but in the address bar I wanted to test and unfortunately I also access it. How to correct the problem? Thanks for your help here is the code :

In the back end in app.js :

```
app.use(express. Static("style"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

// Route pour le logout
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    // Supprime les cookies
    res.clearCookie('loggedIn');
    res.clearCookie('isAdmin');
    res.clearCookie('isClient');

    // Redirige vers la page de connexion
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.redirect('/login.html');
});

// Route pour la connexion d'un utilisateur
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    if (!username || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Veuillez fournir un nom d'utilisateur et un mot de passe." });
    }

    const query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
    try {
        const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(query, [username, password]);

        if (rows.length === 0) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: "Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect." });
        }

        const user = rows[0];
        const isAdministrateur = user.administrateur === 1;
        const isClient = user.client === 1;

        // Set cookies for logged in user
        res.cookie('loggedIn', true);
        res.cookie('isAdmin', isAdministrateur);
        res.cookie('isClient', isClient);

        if (isAdministrateur) {
            return res.redirect('/admin.html');
        } else if (isClient) {
            return res.redirect('/client.html');
        } else {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: "Ce compte n'est pas autorisé à se connecter." });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send("Une erreur est survenue lors de la connexion de l'utilisateur.");
    }
});

// Middleware pour vérifier si l'utilisateur est authentifié
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.cookies.loggedIn) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login.html');
    }
}

// Middleware pour vérifier si l'utilisateur est un administrateur
function isAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.cookies.isAdmin) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login.html');
    }
}

// Middleware pour vérifier si l'utilisateur est un client
function isClient(req, res, next) {
    if (req.cookies.isClient) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login.html');
    }
}


// Route pour la page client.html avec middleware isClient
app.get('/client.html', isAuthenticated, isClient, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client.html'));
});

// Route pour la page admin.html avec middleware isAdmin
app.get('/admin.html', isAuthenticated, isAdmin, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'admin.html'));
});
```

Comment: It seems you are storing passwords in clear text. Please never ever do that as once your database gets compromised, all your users' passwords will be compromised. Please check on how to store passwords securely (in 2023!) and better yet, don't store passwords. Use some secure service that manages authentication for you.

Comment: Thank you very much ok. It's website to test acknwledge.

Comment: I can become admin by simply setting two cookies in my browser? That's not really secure.